# Terminal prompt does't show on macOS Sierra

Tags: terminal, bash, macos

Since I upgraded to Sierra, Terminal no longer loads my bash prompt, making it unusable. When I start it, it doesn't hang, but it stays looking like this:

[image]

I can enter text, but it doesn't do anything. It seems like the bash or tail command is hanging. I have also tried using the terminal window in Android Studio and that just shows a blank screen.

Any idea how I could fix this?

Comment: Do you have anything in your ~/.bash_profile or similar? Might try moving any such files to a different folder then trying again.

Comment: @tubedogg I do, but I have just found that it works if I press ^C. So it doesn't seem to be a problem with bash.

Comment: Yes it is a problem with your bash scripts. You cave a command that doesn't end..

Answer (score 4):

After some debugging I found out that the bash-autocompletion package for brew did cause this. It is clear that if you run `$(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion` the command does not terminate

As a wordaround, you can uninstall it with `brew uninstall bash-autocompletion`. I'd recommend to first update brew by running `brew update && brew upgrade` though.

Digging deeper it turned out the main problem here was the rust compiler. Running `rustc --version` pointed me to a segfault. I uninstalled it using `/usr/local/lib/rustlib/uninstall.sh`, after which the bash autocompletion started to work again. Removing rust as described, and reinstalling it using brew (`brew install rust`) ensured everything worked again